# Drop Down List, display

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a drop down list which is for a news website.

If user selects 1 in the drop-down list,
the page will display an id correspond to 1

if user select 2
the page will display an id correspond to 2

Possible?
Please advice and Submit some Tutorials.

Thank You,

Yours Sincerely,
Help!

Comment: Well you will need a little more than html. i advise getting started with php, only because it is easy to learn the basic. [Php for Beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner)

Comment: any other way beside php? I think it's possible using javascript

Comment: yes you can do it in javascript too. you just need to add an onchange event to your select dropdown

Comment: are you having problem with making the drop-down list of in displaying the page based on what user click?

Comment: Any example that I can browse through? thanks so much for ur help

Comment: Phelios - Yupyup. But I want it to display on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Mmm. You'll need AJAX

Here you have a link to start:

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=10

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use jquery selector methods check below option.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function display() {
                    var Values = $("#drop").val();
                    alert(Values);
                }
                $("select").change(display);

            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="drop">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/Tq8Ag/

At least then the user won't get a non-working select box if javascript is turned off or an error occurs etc.

Hope that helps!

*please note I'm using jQuery here - I think it will be pretty helpful to you*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value`:

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
var thankyouLetter = document.getElementById("thankyou-letter");
var submitIt = function () {
  var rating = document.getElementById("rating").value;
  if (rating === "1") {
    thankyou = "I'm so sad! A 1?";
  }
  else if (rating === "2") {
    thankyou = "So little?";
  }
  else if (rating === "3") {
    thankyou = "Thanks.";
  }
  else if (rating === "4") {
    thankyou = "Thank you!";
  }
  else if (rating === "5") {
    thankyou = "Awesome!!!!!";
  }
  else {
    thankyou = "You need to rate!";
  }
  thankyouLetter.innerHTML = thankyou;
};
submitButton.addEventListener("click", submitIt);
```

```html
<label>What rating?
  <select id = "rating">
    <option value = "xxx">---</option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
    <option value = "4">4</option>
    <option value = "5">5</option>
  </select>
</label>
<button id = "submit">Submit</button>
<p><span id = "thankyou-letter"></span><p>
```

This is just an example of a rating, then a little "thank you letter". A `value` means that you don't have to do `.value` and `getElementById` all the time, but you still have to do some.